# Java DateFormat with ordinal indicator

Tags: java, datetime-format

I tried to update some stuff (is the French version for *SimpleDateFormat*).
Is the first time I'm posting there so please, be kind

There is my code, its working after so much tries!

Creating a method to change the first day which is 1er in France:

```
public static String dateSuffix(final Calendar calendar) {
    final int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    if (date % 30 == 1) if (date == 1) return "er";
    return "";
}
```

Adding the method there:

```
public String getDateAttestation() {
    DateFormat formaterDateAttest = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE d'%s' MMMM yyyy", Locale.FRANCE);
    return String.format(formaterDateAttest.format(dateAttestation.getDateEditor().getDate()), dateSuffix(dateAttestation.getCalendar()));
}
```

Everything is in my View linked to that JDateChooser():

```
dateAttestation = new JDateChooser();
dateAttestation.setDateFormatString("dd MMMM yyyy");
dateAttestation.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance()); // set la date du jour dans le frame
```

Is that decent for you? What should I improve?

Thanks everyone

To optimize my code with community experience.

**UPDATE**

I reproduced the code given from Arvind Kumar Avinash.
My problem now is that I have to import a date chosen with JDateChooser tool in my Frame shown before.

Then I'm parsing the getter:

```
public Date getDateAttestation(Date ignoredDate) {
        return dateAttestation.getDateEditor().getDate();
    }
```

And so

```
 public String getDateAttestation() {
        Date date = new Date();
        date = getDateAttestation(date);
        OffsetDateTime odtDateAttest = date.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        DateTimeFormatter daformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(String.format("EEEE d'%s' MMMM uuuu", dateSuffix(odtDateAttest.getDayOfMonth())), Locale.FRANCE);
        return odtDateAttest.format(daformatter);
    }
```

Is working nicely for the "jeudi 1er décembre 2022", but gives me "vendredi 2' décembre 2022" from this method :

```
static String dateSuffix(final int dayOfMonth) {
        return (dayOfMonth % 30 == 1 || dayOfMonth == 1) ? "er" : "";
    }
```

If I add a space between

```
: " ";
    }
```

I'm getting a space in my result too but I don't want that, any idea? :)

Comment: Regarding **... but gives me "vendredi 2' décembre 2022" ....** - what output are you expecting? I do not know French but when I translate `vendredi 2' décembre 2022` into English, I get `Friday, December 2, 2022` which seems correct but Google translate might be auto-correcting if there are any mistakes.

Comment: Im trying to get vendredi 2 décembre 2022, in France we just using 1er and rest is empty :)

Comment: I have updated the answer to meet this new requirement. Now, my function returns `(dayOfMonth % 30 == 1 || dayOfMonth == 1) ? "er" : "\0"` which meets your requirement.  Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried, my font not taking \0, i downloaded a supporting one but giving me the same result as " " and getting so two espace keys. Maybe i have to iterate the dayOfMonth so just give nothing if not the 1st day of month ?

Comment: Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/VxOFch).

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Calendar` `SimpleDateFormat`, `DateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the two date format classes in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You should also be able to find a date picker that supports java.time.

Comment: This is where java.time excels. [I consider this solution quite elegant myself](https://rextester.com/JOO94473).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

The `java.time` API, released with Java-8 in March 2014, supplanted the [error-prone legacy date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Since then, using this modern date-time API has been strongly recommended.

In case you are getting an instance of `java.util.Date`, you can switch to the modern date-time API by converting it into an `Instant` using [`Date#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getDateAttestation(new Date()));
    }

    static String getDateAttestation(Date date) {
        // In your case, it is
        // Date date = dateAttestation.getDateEditor().getDate();
        OffsetDateTime odt = date.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern(String.format("EEEE d'%s' MMMM uuuu", dateSuffix(odt.getDayOfMonth())), Locale.FRANCE);
        return odt.format(formatter);
    }

    static String dateSuffix(final int dayOfMonth) {
        return (dayOfMonth % 30 == 1 || dayOfMonth == 1) ? "er" : "\0";
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
jeudi 1er décembre 2022
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.